# How can I solve this recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I have a recurrence relation:
[image]

I transformed it into
[image]

How can I prove T(n) is belong to BigOmega(2^n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's look at *T(n) = 2 * T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + 1/2*.

Let us compare this to the recurrence relation where the smaller terms are stripped:

*S(n) = 2 * T(n - 1)*

We can obviously see that

*T(n) = Ω(S(n))*

so it only remains to show that *S(n) = Ω(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

Let us expand *S(n)*:

*S(n) = 2 * T(n - 1)*

*= 2 * 2 * T(n - 2)*

*= 2 * 2 * 2 * T(n - 3)*

We notice that we obtain *2 * 2 * ... * 2 = 2<sup>n</sup>*.

Therefore, *S(n) = Ω(2<sup>n</sup>)* and thus *T(n) = Ω(S(n)) = Ω(2<sup>n</sup>)*. □